# Testing a MySQL INSERT result with Node.js/Sinon

Tags: mysql, node.js, sinon, ava

My application code to test:

```
create(params) {
  let result = {};
  try {
    result = await this.db.query('/* some query */');
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error('Error creating User', e);
  }
  return this._getById(result.insertId);
}
```

I have the `_getById` method in the same class which does exactly what it says...

And my current test (running through Ava):

```
test('it should create a user', async t => {
  const db = mock({
    query: () => {
    },
  });
  const userObj = {
        // some params
  };
  const user = new Users({
    db: db.object,
  });
  const call = {
    request: userObj,
  };
  const result = await user.create(call);
    // test?
});
```

If I try and test anything based off of the `result` variable, ie. the newly created User, I receive the error `"Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined"`. What is my best option with Sinon to test that this `create` method will return a newly created "user"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the `"Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined"` because the following mock doesn't return something

```
const db = mock({
  query: () => {
  },
});
```

If you return something like that

```
const db = mock({
  query: () => {
    return {
      username: "username"
    }
  },
});
```

and in the test the result will have the value and you should be able to use expect to check if you have the expected result:

```
{
  username: "username"
}
```

The problem in this specific test starts when the mock does not return something and also calling mock overrode the value that you assigned here

```
let result = {};
```